# Split a text file based on a specific word

Tags: linux, sed, split, text-processing

I have two text file like this:

> `list.txt`
>
> ```
> file 'aavr-001-1.mp4'
> file 'aavr-001-2.mp4'
> file 'aavr-001-3.mp4'
> file 'ccr-010-1.mp4'
> file 'ccr-010-2.mp4'
> file 'ccr-010-3.mp4'
> file 'vvvw2-031-1.mp4'
> file 'vvvw2-031-2.mp4'
> ```

> `code.txt`
>
> ```
> aavr-001
> ccr-010
> vvvw2-031
> ```

**My code:**

```
for f in $(cat code.txt); do
   s=$(echo $f)
   cat list.txt | sed '/$s/!d' >$s.txt
done
```

I was expecting to get these three files with the following content:

> `aavr-001.txt`
>
> ```
> file 'aavr-001-1.mp4'
> file 'aavr-001-2.mp4'
> file 'aavr-001-3.mp4'
> ```

> `ccr-010.txt`
>
> ```
> file 'ccr-010-1.mp4'
> file 'ccr-010-2.mp4'
> file 'ccr-010-3.mp4'
> ```

> `vvvm2-031.txt`
>
> ```
> file 'vvvw2-031-1.mp4'
> file 'vvvw2-031-2.mp4'
> ```

But in the end I could only get three blank files: `aavr-001.txt` `ccr-010.txt` `vvvw2-031.txt`, not any content in them.

What should I do to fix the problem?

p.s. If I only input like `cat list.txt | sed '/aavr-001/!d' >aavr-001.txt`, I can get the result I want

Comment: Variables are only expanded inside double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: What's the reason for `s=$(echo $f)`? This is essentially the same as `s=$f`

Comment: Why use `sed`? This is basically `grep "$s" list.txt > "$s.txt"`

Comment: Because I found at the beginning of the debugging if I don't use `s=$(echo $f)` processing will have other problems, but just tested again seems to be no longer a problem. Anyway, your last suggestion has solved my problem, thank you.